# Print value to only two decimals places in CGI script

Tags: cgi

```
print <<here;
<div align="center">
<h2>Grades</h2>
<table border ="2" bordercolor="green">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Id#</td><td>Test 1</td><td>Test 2</td><td>Test 3</td><td>Average</td>
  </tr>
here

my @record = $sql->fetchrow_array;  ### there is only one row in resultset

for(my $i = 0; $i < @record; $i++ ) {
  print "<td>$record[$i]</td>";
}
"<td>$avg \%.2f</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</table></div></body></html>";
```

I am having trouble printing  `$avg` to only  two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`printf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) to print a number using a specific format:

```
printf("<td>%0.2f</td>\n", $avg);
```